# Right-click on Windows, with VLC and PyGTK

Tags: python, windows, pygtk, vlc

I'm porting a video application from Linux to Windows and I'm using VLC as media backend. I got a little problem for which I couldn't find yet a solution: the application doesn't react when I'm right-clicking over video image, while the movie is playing. Is like GTK doesn't receive the right-click because of VLC. It seems to be a vout driver problem, because I tested with MPlayer and right-clicking was working, until I used direct3d or gl as video driver. What could be the solution here? I'm using VLC with VLC Python bindings on Windows 7.

Comment: I should mention that I got a similar problem on some Linux systems, with MPlayer. The application doesn't seems to receive right-click events. Anyway, the problem now is how I fix this in Windows...

Comment: There wasn't an official announcement on pygtk.org, but [PyGTK all-in-one installer 2.24.2](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2012-February/020234.html) is available now. It includes a bunch of fixes for Windows-specific bugs. If you're not using that yet, it's worth a try.

Comment: I'm using this version of PyGTK already

Comment: This might be silly, but could it stem from differences in integration with GTK so that the VLC-backend needs to have a GTK event listener connected to it that activates appropriate menu-functions (or what you wish) for right-click events?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
You should just pass ***False*** at **libvlc_video_set_key_input** and **libvlc_video_set_mouse_input** functions.

Example of working code:

```
instance = vlc.Instance()

class VLCWidget(gtk.DrawingArea):
    def __init__(self, *p):
        gtk.DrawingArea.__init__(self)
        self.player = instance.media_player_new()
        def handle_embed(*args):
            self.player.set_hwnd(self.window.handle)
            return True
        self.connect("map", handle_embed)
        self.set_size_request(320, 200)

class Player(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        self._vlc_widget = VLCWidget()
        self.player = self._vlc_widget.player
        self.player.video_set_mouse_input(False)
        self.player.video_set_key_input(False)
        vbox.pack_start(self._vlc_widget, expand=True)
        self._toolbar = self.get_player_control_toolbar()
        self.pack_start(self._toolbar, expand=False)
        self.add(vbox)

        self._vlc_widget.set_events(
            gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
        )
        self._vlc_widget.connect("button-press-event", self.on_vlc_button_press)

    def on_vlc_button_press(self, widget, event):
        print "pressed"

    def get_player_control_toolbar(self):
        tb = gtk.Toolbar()
        tb.set_style(gtk.TOOLBAR_ICONS)
        for tooltip, stock, callback in (
            (_("Play"), gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY, lambda b: self.player.play()),
            (_("Pause"), gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE, lambda b: self.player.pause()),
            (_("Stop"), gtk.STOCK_MEDIA_STOP, lambda b: self.player.stop()),
            ):
            b=gtk.ToolButton(stock)
            b.set_tooltip_text(tooltip)
            b.connect("clicked", callback)
            tb.insert(b, -1)
        tb.show_all()
        return tb

    def main(self, fname):
        self.show_all()
        self.player.set_media(instance.media_new(fname))
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p=Player()
    p.main("path_to_file")
```

Comment: I should have checked the `vlc.py` for it's pretty well documented... Not using gtk but `self.player.video_set_mouse_input(False)` and `self.player.video_set_key_input(False)` were pretty much the hint as mentioned in answer. Life saver..